# How can I initialize a step in sequence?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm new in Spring Batch and I'm trying to execute two steps of a job. Both must initialize something before execute the read, process and write methods. But I'm not getting how can I do it. Every time I launch the job, the two steps initialize at same time. I want they initialize in the sequence of the job.

To put it simply, I did something like that:

```
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(step1())
            .next(step2())
            .build();
}

public Step step1() {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Model1, Model1>chunk(2)
            .reader(reader1())
            .processor(processor1())
            .writer(writer1())
            .build();
}

public Step step2() {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
            .<Model2, Model2>chunk(2)
            .reader(reader2())
            .processor(processor2())
            .writer(writer2())
            .build();
}

@StepScope
public Reader1 reader1() {
    return new Reader1();
}


@StepScope
public Processor1 processor1() {
    return new Processor1();
}

@StepScope
public Writer1 writer1() {
    return new Writer1();
}


@StepScope
public Reader2 reader2() {
    return new Reader2();
}


@StepScope
public Processor2 processor2() {
    return new Processor2();
}

@StepScope
public Writer2 writer2() {
    return new Writer2();
}
```

That's my Reader2 class that I want to initialize after the first step. The Reader1 is the same thing. Both "test" are printed and then steps begin to run.

```
public class Reader2 implements ItemReader<Model2>{

    public Reader2() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    @Override
    public Model2 read() throws Exeption {
    .
    .
    .
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [StepExecutionListener#beforeStep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#stepExecutionListener) for that matter. It is more appropriate for step initialization rather than doing the initialization in the reader's constructor.

Comment: It works with anotation @BeforeStep in initialize! I didn't know it. Thank you very much.